# How do I get xconsole to show the messages on a system with journald?

Tags: systemd, suse, systemd-journald

I would like an old style xconsole on my desktop, ie a terminal which display a scrolling list of syslog message.

Does the journald system have a nice desktop app or is there a simple way to get it to just fill in the correct syslog and message log files so xconsole will work as it used to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something simple like:

```
xterm -T xnotconsole -e journalctl -f
```

ought to work. `-T` sets the window title. You can of course add in things like `-geometry` to set its size (put all xterm options before the `-e`). And you could add in `journalctl` options to filter the messages you want, change the output format, etc.

Though `xconsole` works on my Debian systemd box. It's configured (AFAIK by default in Debian) as systemd forwards to syslog, then rsyslog reads that, then rsyslog writes to /dev/xconsole.

Comment: Should have though of that. Only need to make it a tool now.